# the verb "lever" vs "prise/prize" vs "pry"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Looking at the definitions for the words "lever", "prise (prize)", and "pry" in the dictionary, and only considering the meanings involving a physical action, it looks to me that all three words have the same meaning.  Some of the definitions even *use each other* in their definitions!

Is there a difference between them?  That is to say, I understand that the meanings must be similar, but is there a difference in how to use these words, or where you would expect to find them used?

More specifically, are they freely interchangeable? For example, can I say:

> I want to lever {something} open.
> I want to prise {something} open.
> I want to pry {something} open.

..and have all the three above sentences mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: Yes, similar,  Doesn't the dictionary help.  Perhaps you could copy and paste the definitions you read in the dictionary to this question

Comment: _Pry_ in this sense is an American synonym for _prise_.

Comment: @KateBunting agreed, but in the UK there is a common tool known as a "pry bar", which is never  called a "prise bar" in my experience. It's use is obvious from its name.

Comment: A few people voted to close this question as being answerable with a dictionary.  I don't think it is, so I edited and reworded the question in a way that I think makes Vova's confusion clear.  He knows the definitions in the dictionary: the definitions are the same.  So are the words actually the same in usage?  This is not a trivial question!

Comment: I'm leaving this question open for Richard Winters's reasons above

Comment: You pry something open with a iron or steel bar. The bar gives you leverage. Levers are parts of machines.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the options in "to lever/prise/pry smth open" the same? Thank you!

1. to *pry* something open

Good. This seems like the clear and recommended way to say it, when opening a jar or box with a screwdriver, for example.

2. To *prise* something open

From my perspective in US English, this is quite unusual. But since it's in the dictionary, it might be common in certain regions or dialects.

3. to *lever* something open

In the most common vernacular, "lever" is a noun. So, using it as a verb is a bit more colorful usage of the English language.

I imagine "lever" would apply in building construction situations, or any large scale uses of a "lever".

"pry" has a specific meaning "to force open", and thus matches your example better. "Lever" is not specific to opening.

Someone wouldn't say they "levered open the box" when they could say "pried it open" instead.